# Prestashop 1.6 Override admin Controller not overriding

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to override the AdminCarriersControllerCore, specifically the postProcess method (so that it updates the carrier instead of deleting and creating a new one, because it breaks reference).

To check that it get's overriden first i do:

```
<?php
class AdminCarriersController extends AdminCarriersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct(){
        die(var_dump('constructor'));
    }
}
```

I've put it in the following path

```
modules/<my_module_name>/override/controllers/admin/AdminCarriersController.php
```

It doesn't overrides.

Also tried in:

```
modules/<my_module_name>/controllers/admin/AdminCarriersController.php
```

Also deleted the cache file (which didn't get regenerated automatically as the docs say)

```
rm class_index.php
```

Thanks for any help. [Official Prestashop docs page for overriding](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingaclass)

Note: Yes, I'm aware that there is a reference_id or whatever and that I shouldn't use the carrier_id directly, but the module is already too cryptic and trying to change the carrier_id to the correct one is too risky and too much time-consuming.

Comment: Ok but did you reinstall the module after creating this override?

Comment: Take a look at this thread please : https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/480523-override-front-controller-of-modules/

Comment: @TheDrot I'm modifying the already installed module in prestashop.

Comment: @Melvita I'll check it and post any news

Comment: @monstercode Putting override files in module folders don't do anything. You need to either reinstall module so that files get placed in proper override folder or manually place override files into `override` folder.

Comment: @TheDrot That was it!! Thank you so much. If you write it as the answer i'll mark it as resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing override files in your `module_name/override`does not do anything yet. When installing a module, PrestaShop will check if you have override files in your module and do a check if your overriden class has methods already overriden by another module. If it does, then you won't be able to install the module.

If you have module already installed and you can't reinstall it for some reason then you need to place override file directly into root `override` folder and delete 
file `cache/class_index.php`.

I'm not sure if override files get installed with a module upgrade. I'll check it later and update the answer.

Comment: And for developing purposes, the file is placed in

/override/controllers/admin/AdminCarriersController.php

So modifying that file makes the changes (then of course, I have to save it in the module folder)